# How to access the searchbar using Firefox addon SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to access the searchbar using [Firefox's addon SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/index.html)?

I've seen examples on how to access the menu, context menu and the bookmark sidebar. But I can't find any documentation or tutorial on how to access the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const winUtils = require("sdk/deprecated/window-utils");
var searchbar = winUtils.activeBrowserWindow.document.getElementById("searchbar");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've found that snippet on SO. But is there any documentation on its functionalities? Such as exposed events, attributes, methods, etc.

Comment: Depending on what you expect to find, the [source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/search/content/search.xml) might be self-explanatory